# Android alarm is 12 hours late

Tags: android, xamarin.android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have set an alarm (in an alarm clock app we are developing) for 8:58 (in 24h format).

**The alarm did not fire - alarm icon is still in status bar** - and when I write `adb shell dumpsys alarm` I can see this:

```
Batch{6b33bdb num=1 start=99803288 end=99803288 flgs=0x3}:
  RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{3e3da2e type 0 when 1484078280736 my.app}
  tag=*walarm*:my.app/md5f98255d9820be5cc9672d0645bf1ca12.RingBroadcastReceiver
  type=0 whenElapsed=+11h1m53s125ms when=2017-01-10 20:58:00
  window=0 repeatInterval=0 count=0 flags=0x3
  Alarm clock:
    triggerTime=2017-01-10 08:58:00
    showIntent=PendingIntent{21219cf: PendingIntentRecord{aac3f5c my.app startActivity}}
  operation=PendingIntent{ecde88f: PendingIntentRecord{821c71c my.app broadcastIntent}}

Next wake from idle: Alarm{3e3da2e type 0 when 1484078280736 my.app}
  tag=*walarm*:my.app/md5f98255d9820be5cc9672d0645bf1ca12.RingBroadcastReceiver
  type=0 whenElapsed=+11h1m53s125ms when=2017-01-10 20:58:00
  window=0 repeatInterval=0 count=0 flags=0x3
  Alarm clock:
    triggerTime=2017-01-10 08:58:00
    showIntent=PendingIntent{21219cf: PendingIntentRecord{aac3f5c my.app startActivity}}
  operation=PendingIntent{ecde88f: PendingIntentRecord{821c71c my.app broadcastIntent}}
```

**THE QUESTION IS: How is it possible that `when` is 12 hours after `triggerTime`?**

It seems like 12/24 hour format issue, but my device and also my app and its time picker are all set to 24 hour format. This issue happened just once. When I set a new alarm, it works as expected.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
We are using this code to set the alarm (sorry for Xamarin syntax) and I have tested that the alarmEntity is returning correct time. The problem must be in this code or in the device/android/system stuff. From the `triggerTime=2017-01-10 08:58:00` it seems to me that the code is OK and there is some issue in the system or alarm manager.

```
DateTime closestTrigger = alarmEntity.GetTime();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.Instance;
calendar.Set(CalendarField.Year, closestTrigger.Year);
calendar.Set(CalendarField.Month, closestTrigger.Month - 1);
calendar.Set(CalendarField.DayOfMonth, closestTrigger.Day);
calendar.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, closestTrigger.Hour);
calendar.Set(CalendarField.Minute, closestTrigger.Minute);
calendar.Set(CalendarField.Second, closestTrigger.Second);

var alarmInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.TimeInMillis, mainPendingIntent);
manager.SetAlarmClock(alarmInfo, ringPendingIntent);
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I've found one more important line in the same dumpsys alarm log:

```
Next alarm clock information: 
user:0 pendingSend:false time:1484035080736 = 2017-01-10 08:58:00 = -58m6s876ms
```

..which means the alarm was missed, but the system didn't even try to present it, the logcat didn't show any activity at all around the 8:58. And still not clear why would the system reschedule the alarm to 20:58.

Comment: What is the device's time zone set to? Are you setting the alarm time for UTC? It confuses me that you say it works when you set a new alarm, what other case is there?

Comment: Timezone is set automatically to UTC+1 and I am working with local time. It also confuses me, it works all the time, just this one alarm is for some weird reason scheduled to 20:58 although I had set 8:58. And also I see 8:58 in the UI. I haven't tried to deactivate and activate it again yet because I could loose this rare situation.

Comment: It could be you made this alarm whilst still developing and is actually set for 12 hours. Or has some other flags associated with it.

Comment: It happened on the version from google play, not developing version. Alarms work ok for most users, but we are still investigating some issues from a few users, this might be it. But it really doesn't make sense to me, how can 'triggerTime' be correct and 'when' 12 hours later..

Comment: To clarify, for these users that encounter the problem of the alarm getting pushed back 12 hours, do they actually receive the alarm 12 hours later or is it pushed back another 12 hours?

Comment: @nick friskel I am not sure, didn't have a chance to test it

Comment: Ok well can you post the full code of what the alarm triggers?  PendingIntents, receivers, services etc

Comment: The problem is likely with you `mainPendingIntent`.. if you can post it and the intent that it triggers I can try to figure it out.

Comment: @nickfriskel Ok, here you can see the code: http://pastebin.com/0Wrz4ZC2
However I think that intents are ok, because as I said, there was none activity in the logcat at the time when the alarm should ring - this must be problem with alarm manager, calendar, android sdk or something like that